# Controller, and model and view using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view

I may have a very simple question, but I've no idea how to answer it, I always got the same error

I want to set up a news website and I would like all my articles to show up on the home page.

I created first a model for `Pages` with a home page. And then I generated a scaffold for `articles` so with all views available (index show ..)

Now I would like my article's `index` page to show up in the home page, is that possible ? how can I do it ?

In general how do we access generable variable that are in a controller in another page ?

here is the website : http://safe-tor-3522.herokuapp.com

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? to make your pages#index action the home page, or to include a list of pages on your existing home page ?

Comment: In fact now when I create a new article, the article show up 
in the articles/index page . Now I would like my articles to show up on the home page or let say only the three last articles.. 
thx you

Answer (score 2):

- to make your `index` action on `PagesController` the home page for your site, juste add this *at the bottom of your `routes.rb`, just before `end`* :

  ```
  root to: 'pages#index'
  ```
- to show some articles on the home page, you have to retrieve the resources in the home controller (as @arjan told), and maybe use a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) to avoid view code duplication.

other than that, as you seem a bit lost, i advise you to follow the [getting started with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial on rails guides. You should really read carefully and thoroughly all the guides, it is well written, it covers your needs and is a bare minimum to know about rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could just retrieve the resources in your pages controller.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

end
```